# Need help to create a SSRS RDL report in specified format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have to develop a RDL report in the following format:

[image]

I have stored procedure returning first block result set i.e. with **Sr.No.** but don't know how to return result for second block i.e. for <----Current----> <---Last---> block because here I have to show values next to each Label.

Do we need to create multiple DataSet for this task OR we can achieve this in a single stored procedure?

Anybody suggest me how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach in this case would be to add the `Label` information to the underlying stored procedure, i.e. the same information repeadted for each `Code`, then only display this information once for each `Code` in group footer rows.

This assumes that you can't just calculate the Label values for each `Code` from the rest of the DataSet.

So, making some guesses about your data and assuming your updated DataSet looks like this:

[image]

You can create a report similar to this:

[image]

Note that the `Label` information is displayed only once for each `Code` since the information is in the group footer rows. Just specify the `Label` fields without any aggregation; this will just take the first row's values.

Results look to match your requirements:

[image]

You could approach this other ways, e.g. using the Lookup function or with Subreports, but this approach only required one table and one DataSet so seems simplest to me.

Comment: +1 AWESOME...Exactly what i wanted.Your solution really helped me out.many thanks for your reply.stackoverflow rocks...

Comment: Cool, glad it helped you out!